# Matlab. Quad function : ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab

I am using quad function and i am getting that error

```
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

That's what i have:

```
function out = ray_fading(phi, gamma_b_bar,b)
out = (2*(sin(phi)).^2)/(2*(sin(phi)).^2+ b*gamma_b_bar);
```

And i use quad here:

```
EbNodB = [0:0.51:40];
gamma_b_bar = 10.^(EbNodB/10);
M=2;
a=(4/log2(M))*(1-(1/sqrt(M)));
b=3*log2(M)/(M-1);

for j = 1:length(gamma_b_bar)     
  Pb_bar = [Pb_bar (a/pi)* quad('ray_fading',0,pi/2,[],[],gamma_b_bar(j),b)];
end
figure(1);
semilogy(EbNodB,Pb_bar)
xlabel('SNR, EbNo(dB)');
ylabel('Bit error probability, Pe');
title('Theoretical results of BER of M-QAM');
```

I dont know why that error when Pb_bar has the same length of ray fading when i am passing the gamma_bar_b(j) ...

Some help would be great, thanks :)

Comment: It's not the answer you're looking for but, avoid growing vectors in loops. Preallocate memory :-)

Comment: What is Pb_bar? you didn't define it and i think you didn't call quad function correctly? There is not possible parameter after "trace" in quad func documentation http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quad.html

Comment: Pb_bar is the error Probability, and you are true is not defined, it should be Pb_bar=[], but that is not so important. When i call quad i am calling the ray_fading function, with the parameters needed, is it incorrect? I thought i could do that

Comment: FYI, in addition to fixing your actual issues, [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) (or [`quadgk`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadgk.html) in older Matlab versions) might be a better choice than `quad`. In particular, `integral` supports vector-valued functions so you could remove your `for` loop (there's also [`quadv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadv.html) for that in older versions).

Answer (score 1):

There are two simple changes I would make to begin with:

```
quad('ray_fading',0,pi/2,[],[],gamma_b_bar(j),b)
```

should be

```
quad(@(x)(ray_fading(x,gamma_b_bar(j), b)),0,pi/2)
```

and

```
out = (2*(sin(phi)).^2)/(2*(sin(phi)).^2+ b*gamma_b_bar);
```

should be

```
out = (2*(sin(phi)).^2)./(2*(sin(phi)).^2+ b*gamma_b_bar);
```

(Notice the ./ rather than the /)

**Edit**

However, we can probably do quite a bit better. We can compute your [integral analytically](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=2%2a%28Sin%5Bx%5D%29%5E2%2F%282%2a%28Sin%5Bx%5D%29%5E2%2Bb%29&random=false), so these lines are equal

```
quad(@(x)(ray_fading(x,gamma_b_bar(j), b)),0,pi/2) 
pi/2 * (1-sqrt(b*gamma_b_bar(j)/(2+b*gamma_b_bar(j))))
```

So now we can replace the whole for loop with:

```
Pb_bar = a/2 * (1-sqrt(b*gamma_b_bar./(2+b*gamma_b_bar)));
```